# How to send email once in Django admin after i have changed user inlines?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-2.2

For example, let's say I have code like this:

**models.py**

```
class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("account.Account", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_choices = [(1.0, "Waiting for info"),
                      (2.0, "Processing"),
                      (3.0, "Problem detected"),
                      (4.0, "Accepted"),
                      (5.0, "Rejected")]
    status = models.FloatField(choices=status_choices, default=status_choices[0][0])
```

**admin.py**

```
class ApplicationInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    models = Application


@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ApplicationInLine,)
```

Now on the Django admin page, I want to change user application status.
If I have only one application under one user, then it is fine, I can use signals to notify the user via email that status has been changed.

But if I have more than one application under one user, for example 4 and I want to make change all application statuses at once before I click Save button on admin, then signals will trigger 4 times.

I have already tried to overwrite the save method too, but I have got the same results.

Does anybody know how can I send an email only once, even when there has been a change in multiple applications under one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelAdmin` has a `save_formset()` method which is called when inlines are saved. What about overriding that method and checking for changes in the formset? Something like:

```
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ApplicationInLine,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        if formset.has_changed():
            # Send your mail to user
        super().save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```